# How to register javascript in ASP.NET MVC action?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

For example, I want to show a jQuery dialog after insert or edit a record in Action, in webform I can use the follow way to register js script to the page:

```
page.RegisterStartupScript(key, "<script language='javascript' defer>" + script + "</script>");
```

but this doesn't work in MVC, so how can I do this?

thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In ASP.NET MVC scripts are not registered in controller actions. There's a separation between controllers and views. So you could directly put the `script` in the corresponding view:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="somescript.js"></script>
```

When the view is rendered it will load the script. Now if you are doing AJAX and you want to add a script inside the success callback you could create the `script` element and append it to the DOM:

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.src = 'somescript.js';
$('#someElement').append(script);
```

Comment: Your means I just write the js script to the view page? but how can I call this js function from the action? for example in my view page, I just need to call a jQuery dialog :

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {      
    $("#dialog").dialog("destroy");         
});
 </script>

Answer (score 0):

```
static async register(req, res, next) {
    try {
        const { email, name, password } = req.body;
        if (!email) {
            throw {
                name: "Email is required",
            };
        }
        if (!name) {
            throw {
                name: "Name is required",
            };
        }
        if (!password) {
            throw {
                name: "Password is required",
            };
        }

        const user = await User.create({ email, password, name });

        res.status(201).json({
            id: user.id,
            name: user.name,
            email: user.email,
        });
    } catch (error) {
        next(error);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.